# Is there a way to hide the title bar, but keep the buttons in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, hide, titlebar

I was wondering if I could hide the title bar in Java Swing, but keep the maximize, minimize, and close buttons.

I've tried adding `frame.setUndecorated(true);` but it removes the maximize, minimize, and close buttons completely.

Here is my code:

```
public Display(String title, int width, int height) {
        Display.width = width;
        Display.height = height;

        Display.absWidth = width;
        Display.absHeight = height;

        Display.d = new Dimension(width, height);

        setProperties();

        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.fullWindowContent", true);
        frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.transparentTitleBar", true);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        handleResize();
        handleQuit();

        //showSplashScreen();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the native buttons then it depends on the operating system.

- Windows: No, you will have to use `frame.setUndecorated(true);` and replicate the buttons yourself. This would then work on all platforms, but to achieve a native look you’d have to implement it for each individually.
- macOS: If you use jdk 12 or newer you can achieve it using:

```java
rootPane.putClientProperty(“apple.awt.fullWindowContent“, true);
rootPane.putClientProperty(“apple.awt.transparentTitleBar“, true);
```

This is taken from the jdk test cases:

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 300, 100);
    rootPane = frame.getRootPane();
    JComponent contentPane = (JComponent) frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
    rootPane.putClientProperty("apple.awt.fullWindowContent", true);
    rootPane.putClientProperty("apple.awt.transparentTitleBar", true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
});
```

Note that all creation and modification of the ui should happen on the Swing main thread using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait`.

What exactly is your goal in removing the title bar but keeping the buttons?

Comment: I am attempting to achieve something like CleanMyMac's window. [Example](https://imgix.setapp.com/app/78/screenshots/1580293179-5e315c3b6d037.png?auto=format&ixlib=php-2.3.0&q=75&w=1280)

Comment: If you are only targeting macOS then using the client property approach is the simplest solution. You’ll have to include a manual spacer so your content isn’t overlapped by the window buttons. If you’ll also target other operating system you can still got for the same solution on macOS but you’ll have to make sure the spacer is only added on macOS and no important content is placed in the spacer itself.

Comment: I added the lines, however it didn't seem to hide the title bar?? It may be because of all the other things this poor frame is put through later on.

Comment: Did you add the properties to the JFrame or the root pane? You’ll have to use the latter which can be obtained through JFrame#getRootPane. Also make sure you are actually running it on java 13.

Comment: I am running Java 13.0.1 and I added the following lines `frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.fullWindowContent", true);
        frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.transparentTitleBar", true);`

Comment: Well without seeing the rest of your code I can’t tell why it isn’t working for you. Have you tried it with a plain frame?

Comment: Never-mind, it's too long... I added it to the original question.

Comment: It did work with a blank frame, it may be because I am adding a canvas.

Comment: Please remove `frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);` and add to the frames content pane (`frame.getContentPane()`) instead of the frame directly.

Comment: When I made a new JFrame it did work, so I am assuming that something else is happening in my code, however your answer is correct. Thank You.

Comment: I was able to get it to work when I compiled the program to a JAR file. Thank you for the help and support...