# Change default GUI colors in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to change the title bars and menu bars of my app to be a solid color.  I'm using UIManager.put to change the defaults but it's not working.  I've tried with both the default system theme and the Nimbus theme.

Here's the code I used for the default system theme:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        adjustLookAndFeel();          

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalendarAlertMainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

....//rest of main function.  Nothing custom

}

private static void adjustLookAndFeel() {
        UIManager.put("control", Color.RED);
        UIManager.put("menu", Color.RED);
        UIManager.put("Menu.background", Color.RED);
        UIManager.put("MenuBar.background", Color.RED);
}
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

As you can see, the menu bar color doesn't change and the red in the title bar is frosted/not saturated. Also, when I take the focus off the window, the title bar color changes back to white.

Here's the code adjusted for Nimbus.

```
private static void adjustLookAndFeel() {
    UIManager.put("control", Color.RED);
    UIManager.put("menu", Color.RED);
    UIManager.put("Menu.background", Color.RED);
    UIManager.put("MenuBar.background", Color.RED);
    UIManager.put("nimbusBase", Color.RED);
    UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", Color.RED);    
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Slightly better but the title bar still isn't right.  It has the same issue with the title bar not going full, saturated red and turning white when the window is not in focus.  Also the only way the menu bar changes color is if I adjust "nimbusBase" and "nimbusBlueGrey".  That also changes the button colors (other windows in the app have buttons) to red, which I don't want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The title bar isn't under the controller of the look and feel delegate - in this case at least, it's provided by the system itself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61374180/12174160 might answer your question. You will need to add your own padding for the titlebar though.